# xs:attributeGroup value restriction

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have this xsd

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="PropertyAttributes">
    <xs:attribute name="IsAttached" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
    <xs:attribute name="IsStatic" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
  </xs:attributeGroup>
```

I like to restrict this case
IsAttached=true IsStatic=true

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this in XSD 1.0; you have to either move to XSD 1.1 (the only freely available processor that I know of is Xerces, and that is in beta status) OR augment your XSD 1.0 model with Schematron (the latter being XSLT 1.0/2.0 based, you have options galore).